# How to display html/javascript code as normal text on page

Tags: php, xss, user-input

In my application user can post their status updates, in which there is possibility that thy might post some code html/javascript or any other script, I am storing it in my database, and showing it on web page, I want to show this code without affecting the page, the code should be displayed as normal text, it should not run either while processing at server side or  while loading at client side...How can I achieve this? and also I am storing it without any processing like `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `strip_tags()` or any other filter...is it good not to do any processing on it? are there any threats associated with it? If i should perform any operation on it then what functions I should use to be on safer side and achieve my aim of showing user input as it is as normal/plain text.

**Update**: 
After reading all the answers, I think I should go and read more about `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Use this while displaying the text - you shouldn't have to do anything special when reading or storing it.

FYI: This is probably a good idea for any text that you're displaying that was user-created - prevents XSS, CSRF, and all those other nasty injection issues.

**EDIT**

Looks like I'm outvoted here, but I recommend not encoding the data when you store it, but rather being careful when displaying the data. It's more consistent, while allowing your data to be pure.

For example, you can query the data directly `WHERE SOME_TEXT LIKE '%<script>%'` instead of `WHERE SOME_TEXT LIKE '%&lt;script&gt;'`, so the data access is simpler. You can display the data harmlessly on things like reports or desktop applications. And if you're consistent about encoding data on the display side, you never have to think about whether or not you already encoded it on the input (which would result in double-encoding, very ugly), so you can safely always encode your output, regardless of whether or not you considered this to be an unsafe data entry point.

Comment: In what way does it prevent CSRF and injection?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I guess it doesn't prevent CSRF directly, but CSRF can come in combination with XSS. By injection, I'm talking about injecting javascript on the page, not SQL injection or anything that would hurt the server.

Comment: I guess the word "injection" makes sense in that context, but in a web security context it tends to refer to the server side rather than the client (which would be XSS)

Comment: Yep, all semantics - XSS, SQL injection, etc., can all be classified under the umbrella of [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) are for.

And yes, you definitely should be escaping user provided data before inserting it into the DB. `mysql_real_escape_string()` will achieve this, but as per the big red box on the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), along with all other `mysql_*` functions it is deprecated. You should look in to using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

While the existing answers already mention `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`, I recommend you apply these when **storing** the text, as opposed to applying them when **displaying** the text. The rationale for this is twofold:

- If you (or someone else) add another view on the same data at a later time, you won't be bitten, if this is forgotten (Principle of least suprise)
- You will display data much more often than store it, so you suffer the calculation penalty much fewer times.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  This is the de-facto "display html as text" function.

You *should* be storing it with `mysql_real_escape_string` (in fact you should use properly paramterized queries with PDO/mysqli) to prevent injection, but that does not affect the raw data that would be displayed.  Use `htmlspecialchars` when you retrieve it from the DB and are ready to *display* it, not when you store it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to display formatted code. But to prevent the code from executing and not displaying you'll need to convert the text to character entities. > becomes >, < becomes &lt, etc.

You could do this by using PHP, for example:

```
<?php echo htmlentities('function getSize() {  var myFSO = new
ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var filepath =
document.upload.file.value;   var
thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
  var size = thefile.size;  alert(size
+ " bytes"); }'); ?>
```

As your system relies on user input, you might have to rely on AJAX to actually process the user input and convert it to HTML entities.